# Terraform Destroys GitHub Team Instead of Updating it For New Members

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform script to manage members of my GitHub team. It works fine if:

1. An existing team member's role is changing
2. A new user is being added when the team is being created as well

Where the script is puzzling to me is when a team exits, it contains users, and a new user is being added. Instead of adding the new user to the team and thus what I expect to be an update in place operation, a destroy plus replace is done instead. Terraform will delete the original team [ that consisted of me and the user I added when the script was ran for the first time, when this team was also created for the first time ] create a new team and replace the second user with the this new third one [ the first user being me I am added by default my credentials are the ones being used to create the team in the first place ].

Concrete example : currently i have no teams, but i would like to add user A to test_team_1. I fill in these requirements and run terraform plan. Terraform lets me know that a team called test_team_1 will be created and to it we will add user A. On terraform apply I see a new team on GitHub called test_team_1 which has 2 members, me and user A.

Now i am asked to add user B to the same team. When I run terraform plan i am told that instead of updating the team to include one more user, test_team_1 will be deleted. Terraform further tells me that this is happening because the user B has a different username that user A and that this forces a replace operation to occur. If i now run terraform apply, the original test_team_1 is deleted, a new one created and now it has two members me and the new user B.

I need to make sure terraform can add more users overtime without having to delete the team and have only me, the creator, and the new user as members.

Code example:

Child Module :

```
module Test_Child_Module {
  source = "./modules/GitHubAccessRequest"
  owner = var.owner
  team_name = ["test_team_1", "test_team_2"]
  username = "user-a"
  role = "member"
}
```

Parent Module Code

```
resource "github_team" "team" {
  for_each = toset(var.team_name)
  name = each.key
}

resource "github_team_membership" "some_team_membership" {
  for_each = toset(var.team_name)
  team_id  = github_team.team[each.key].id
  username = var.username
  role     = var.role
}
```

for a given user and list of teams, that user will be added to the team for a specific role, teams will be created if they dont exist.

Comment: Can you post the relevant Terraform code?

Comment: edited the question to include code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain I fully understand how this code is being applied, but if it is the case that when you come to add `user-b` you simply modify the `username` param in the module definition, then the behaviour does make sense.

Terraform works on the principle that it will manage each resource during its lifetime. Therefore you cannot write your code to only describe an incremental change, it has to describe the entire state of your infrastructure. Each time you run Terraform, it will compare the entire state as described by your code, with the actual entire state, and then apply any differences.

As I am reading your code at the moment, you only ever have a single `github_team_membership` resource per team, which you sometimes have the `username` set to `user-a` and sometimes is set to `user-b`. Terraform will interpret that is a single `github_team_membership`. I think you in fact want one per user, per team. To be more specific, if you have 2 teams with 2 members each, then your code needs to describe 4 `github_team_membership` resources. If you have 10 in each, then you need 20 `github_team_membership` resources. Each `github_team_membership` resource describes the individual membership of a specific user.

If you are using a recent version of Terraform (and therefore can loop modules), this might be a better way to go, where the code iterates through each team, calling a module, which then iterates through each team member that should be a member of that team:

(Disclaimer: untested but hopefully gives you the idea)

**main.tf**

```
variable "owner" {}

variable "default_users" {
  type = list(map(string))
  default = [ 
              { name = "user-a", role = "member" },
              { name = "user-b", role = "member" }
            ]
}

variable "teams" {
  type = map()
  default = {
    test_team_1 = {},
    test_team_2 = {
      users = [ { name = "user-a", role = "member" },
                { name = "user-c", role = "some_other_role" } 
              ]
    }
  }
}

module "github_team" {
  source = "./modules/GitHubTeam"  
  for_each = var.teams
   
  owner = var.owner
  team_name = each.key
  users = lookup(each.value, "users", var.default_users)
}
```

Note: the `lookup()` function will check a map for the specified key, and in the event it does not exist, return the 3rd param. So using this technique in the case of `test_team_1`, `var.default_users` will be returned, where as in the case of `test_team_2` the custom supplied list of users will be used instead.

**./modules/GitHubTeam/main.tf**

```
  variable "owner" {}
  variable "team_name" {}
  variable "users" {
    type = list(map(string))
  }
  
  resource "github_team" "team" {
    name = var.team_name
  }

  # Create one team membership per user passed in the users list
  resource "github_team_membership" "team_membership" {
    for_each = toset(var.users)
    team_id  = github_team.team.id
    username = each.value["name"]
    role     = each.value["role"]
  }
```

Apologies if I have entirely misunderstood and this is no use.

Comment: your understanding is accurate, thanks for your answer ! i think this is exactly what i needed. i will test this approach out before accepting the answer but i am positive this will do the trick

Comment: on my second pass through of your answer i see the point you are trying to make with one github_membership being created per user. in my case that happened too as the total number of users was always one, it was the number of teams that varied for a single terraform apply. on the second iteration of the apply given a new username thats when i got the error. still working on understanding your answer but do you have any thoughts on this ? i suspect we might run into the same situation

Comment: i feel this is going to give us the same error clockworknet, the way my pipeline is setup is that i get request to add new users over time where the new user is one person and this person must be assigned to multiple teams. so user remains constant and teams is an array, works the first time if the team has no other members but if i get another request with a different user for the same team as the previous request even though i iterate through the list of teams for this user, thinking that the iteration causes creates a new membership it still tries to replace the team

Comment: do you think that one needs to maintain a local copy of the list of users for a given team in the code perhaps? pass that along with the new user everytime?

Comment: submitted this as an issue with terraform as well : https://github.com/integrations/terraform-provider-github/issues/960

Comment: Hi - I have added some detail to the description part of my answer, tho I am still not clear about how this is being applied, so my answer may be misunderstanding your issue.

Comment: Your 3rd comment I think describes the issue. You appear to be writing code to deal with a single user during a pipeline run. You need to deal with _all_ users during _every_ pipeline run. Therefore when receiving a request to add a new user, you need to take a codebase that describes all current users, and a new user to that codebase, then apply the entire codebase against your infrastructure.

Comment: it was indeed what you said. i created a new team and imported it as a state, i also imported the git_membership for the single member that existed [ user a]. this resulted in terraform having knowledge of both resources, the team as well as a prexisting member. when i ran the pipeline again for user b, this time terraform added user b instead of trying to replace user a, cause it knew of its membership. thank you clockworknet your insight was very useful for this terraform newbie

Comment: Glad you got sorted. Terraform takes a little getting used to, but once you are there it is really useful :)